# count the number of unique users per day who logged in from both iphone and web

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assuming I have 2 tables iPhone and Web.
This is the columns inside the table

```
Iphone: ts / user id / iphone session ID
Web:   ts / user id / web session ID
```

I want the result to look like this

```
iphone_user web_user    day
1              0    2021-09-10
1              1    2021-09-12
0              1    2021-09-11
```

But, my result look like this. It seems the day 11th is not in web table, and I cannot call both date table.

```
iphone_user web_user    day
    1          0    2021-09-10
    1          1    2021-09-12
    0          1    (null)
```

This is my current code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT sub.*

FROM ( select count (distinct iphone.user_ID) as Iphone_user, 
      count(distinct web.user_ID) web_user, 
      extract('day' from iphone.ts) as day
      from Iphone  
      FULL OUTER JOIN WEB
      ON Iphone.user_id = Web.User_ID
      and web.ts = iphone.ts
      group by day
     ) sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select cleaned_ate, sum(is_iphone) as iphone, sum(is_web) as web
from ((select distinct user_id, 1 as is_iphone, 0 as is_web, cleaned_time::date as cleaned_date
       from iphone
      ) union all
      (select distinct user_id, 0 as is_iphone, 1 as is_web, cleaned_time::date as cleaned_date
       from web
      )
     ) iw
group by cleaned_date;
```